# Module Not Found: react-refresh/runtime.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, vercel

**Problem:**

I'm encountering a "Module not found" error for react-refresh/runtime.js in my React project. The error message indicates the attempted import falls outside of the project's src directory.This error shows up live browser whenever I run "npm start".

**Attempts Made:**

1. Webpack Configuration:

I tried modifying my webpack.config.js file in the node_modules directory to include an alias and resolve. require() for a shortcut to react-refresh/runtime.js. However, this didn't work. I didn't add a web.config.js to the root of the directory because it does not work in my create react app project neither does craco.

2. Moving react-refresh Folder:

I considered moving the react-refresh folder into the src directory for a quicker solution. However, this is not ideal due to concerns about API usage within the folder.

3. Absolute Import (Not Preferred):

Adjusting the import statements in my code to use the absolute path to react-refresh/runtime.js might be a simple solution, but it's less maintainable in the long run.

**Sub Problem**:

The project worked perfect at first. After deploying it to Vercel. I received an error that stated:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdwSd.png)

After using npm to rebuild the project. I first deleted the package.json-lock file and npm_modules directory. This has not resolved the issue. At least I haven't pushed it to production as yet. But it has only proven to create more issues. This is a description of the problem and a image is attached below.

"ERROR in ./src/App.js 1:40-126

Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /home/vboxuser/repos/official-baboon-/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBFWz.png)

Please I look forward to your solutions on what can work. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that your project is called `official-baboon-`. Is that correct? The trailing hyphen seems weird to me, could it be that you have a typo in your `package.json` or some other similar file?

Comment: That is correct. I looked through the package.json file and found something odd. The name of the project is called baboon-website but the actual directory of the project is called baboon-website-. I validated the 'json' file using a validator tool. It came back valid. Then, there is a pair stored in the package.json as " "-": "^0.0.1",". What would you suggest I do?

Comment: Well, you could try making the name of the directory and the name of the project match, for instance by renaming the directory?

Comment: I tried your solution. The problem remains the same.

Comment: Also, I tried moving the react-refresh outside of the node_modules directory placing it inside a utils folder in the src directory, and updating the import statements. That solution did not work.